# Grossly inefficient wordpress loops!

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, loop

I'm working on a site at the moment for an orchestra. The various members need to be listed, according to their instrument. The members have a custom post type of biography and I'm capturing the instrument value via a custom field.

The only way I can figure out how to display the relevant people in their relevant sections is to loop again and again through the custom post type, displaying the people that play a particular instrument by comparing the meta value.

Code looks like this:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'biographies', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ); ?>

    <ul class="no-bull hijax">
        <?php $biog = new WP_Query($args);
            if( $biog->have_posts() ) : while( $biog->have_posts() ) : $biog->the_post();
                $player = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'player', true);
                if ($player == 'yes') :
                    $instrument = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'instrument', true);
                    if ($instrument == 'violin') :
                    ?>
                        <li><a id="artist_id_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="nb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> : <?php echo($instrument); ?></li>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                endif;
            endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_query();
        $biog = new WP_Query($args);
            if( $biog->have_posts() ) : while( $biog->have_posts() ) : $biog->the_post();
                $player = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'player', true);
                if ($player == 'yes') :
                    $instrument = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'instrument', true);
                    if ($instrument == 'viola') :
                    ?>
                        <li><a id="artist_id_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="nb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> : <?php echo($instrument); ?></li>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                endif;
            endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_query(); 
        $biog = new WP_Query($args);
            if( $biog->have_posts() ) : while( $biog->have_posts() ) : $biog->the_post();
                $player = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'player', true);
                if ($player == 'yes') :
                    $instrument = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'instrument', true);
                    if ($instrument == 'cello') :
                    ?>
                        <li><a id="artist_id_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="nb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> : <?php echo($instrument); ?></li>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                endif;
            endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_query();
```

etc. etc. ad nauseum. (there are currently 12 loops on the page!!)

This is clearly totally inefficient, but quite simply, I don't know how to write better code that this and need some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with one loop, you just need a valid sort order right? Players with one instrument, followed by the next and so on..

**UPDATE:** *Following on the asker's comment, you can still use one query and use `rewind_posts()` to iterate the loop as many times as you need, ie. do something like this to get a custom sort..*

```
<?php
// Add the instruments into the array below, in the order you want them in.
$instruments = array( 'violin', 'viola', 'cello' );

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'biographies', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'nopaging' => true,
    'surpress_filters' => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'player',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'instruments',
            'value' => $instruments,
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    ),
); 

$bios = new WP_Query( $args);
?>

<?php if( $bios->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <ul class="no-bull hijax">

    <?php
    foreach( $instruments as $instrument ) :

        while( $bios->have_posts() ) : $bios->the_post();

            $player_instrument = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'instrument', true );

            if( $instrument != $player_instrument )
                continue;
        ?>

        <li><a id="artist_id_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="nb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> : <?php echo $player_instrument; ?></li>

        <?php 

        endwhile; 
        rewind_posts();

    endforeach;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

See if that has the desired effect.. :)

Comment: Hi - cheers for your help. I should have mentioned that I need to specify the order of the instruments. So violin, viola, cello etc. Your code works great, but I can't specify the order in with the instruments appear... Any thoughts?!

Comment: I'll think of something... watch this space..

Comment: Have updated my answer with new sample code, hope that helps. :)

Comment: sorry for the delay, family fun! Anyhoo it works! What an elegant solution, thank you so much for your time and beautiful code!

Comment: You're welcome Richard... :) **Aside:** kaiser and Doug's suggestion of using terms would be better, term checking is cheaper than meta checking, i just wanted to provide a solution using the data you have, but i'd agree with them that terms would be more ideal(at least in theory, because terms are cached).

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend using custom taxonomies. An intersection between 'Instrument' and 'Player' taxonomies would make short work of this. But if that's not practical, perhaps this might work:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'biographies',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_key' => 'instrument',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value'
);

query_posts($args);

while(have_posts()) : the_post();
  $inst = get_post_meta($post_id, 'instrument', true);
  $player = get_post_meta($post_id, 'player', true);
  if ('yes' == $player) {
  ?>
    <li><a id="artist_id_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="nb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> : <?php echo $inst; ?></li>
  <?php
  }

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehm... you don't need to write a loop again and again. Only work on the part that get's changed. The loop will through all datasets anyway. Btw: I wouldn't make custom fields for this. A "instruments" taxonomy with "violin", "viola", etc. as term would be much easier and give you much more possibilities [(namely template tags)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/), eg. making subtaxs like "wind instruments", "percussion instruments", etc. You should also move the `if` statement inside of the `<li>` element, as it doesn't change either. The only thing is the `if $instrument == ''` and the `echo $instrument;` (which can be written without the surrounding `()`).

```
   if ($instrument == 'violin') : // only $instrument changes, right?
   ?>
     <li>
        <a id="artist_id_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="nb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a> : <?php echo($instrument); ?>
     </li>
   <?php
   elseif ($instrument == 'violin') :
      // do stuff...
   endif;
```

---

**Edit:** You could utilize a custom taxonomy named "instruments" and then filter you query in the desired order:

```
// @link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists  
if ( taxonomy_exists('instruments') ) :
  // @link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term
  if ( has_term( 'instruments', 'viola', get_post_ID() ) ): 
    # DO STUFF HERE, eg. echo term
  endif;
endif;
```

Just make one loop and inside the while-loop just question the term and echo/display stuff. You could, instead of using the `if ( has_term(`, also use a switch for more readability.

*Using this solution avoids further DB calls with `get_post_meta()` - afaik this calls the DB and not the post object - for every instrument.*

Comment: Cheers @kaiser, my problem is that I have to specify the order in which the instruments appear, so it has to go: violin, viola, cello, bass etc etc. Ie. Not alphabetically

Comment: see my edit for further information.