# How to return results of a get_posts() in explicitly defined order

Tags: query-posts, get-posts, sort, loop

I'm trying to create a loop of explicity ordered posts, for example:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'include'         => '1,3,8,4,12' ); ?>

<?php get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

The results are ordered by date by default, and there is no orderby option to return the posts in the order they were entered. There have been multiple bug/feature requests posted about this in Trac, but so far no luck. I've mucked around in the core files a bit but haven't gotten anywhere with it.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this behavior?

Cheers,
Dalton

Comment: @Dalton, is a post order plugin out of the question? You could then use `'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC'`

Comment: In this case that wouldn't work - I'm actually returning attachments, each with different parents, so menu_order becomes irrelevant. Many thanks for the response!

Comment: @Dalton, perhaps I am misunderstanding your problem, but in the media uploader box, if you go to "gallery" you can reorder images by assigning them numbers and then again as suggested above use `'orderby' => 'menu_order, 'order' => 'ASC'`

Comment: Just a sidenote: You can use multiple arguments with orderby separated by space: `&order_by=date ID` for ex.

Comment: @eileen.carpenter: The problem in my case is that each attachment could theoretically have a different parent, making menu_order irrelevant. Each of the attachment IDs in my query could potentially have the same menu order. I'm passing the included posts via a shortcode, so I need to return the attachments in the order given.

Comment: @kaiser: I don't think that will fix my problem here, but that's way cool and I didn't know about that!

Comment: You could do something similar to what i've [done here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11035/grossly-inefficient-wordpress-loops/11044#11044), you'd just use an array of IDs instead of instruments(and minus all the other stuff that's not applicable to your case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I was determined to find a way to do this, and I think I've got it. I had hoped to find a simpler solution and avoid having to use a new WP_Query object, but it's just too ingrained into how the loop works. First, we have a couple of utility functions:

```
// Set post menu order based on our list  
function set_include_order(&$query, $list) {
    // Map post ID to its order in the list:
    $map = array_flip($list);

    // Set menu_order according to the list     
    foreach ($query->posts as &$post) {
      if (isset($map[$post->ID])) {
        $post->menu_order = $map[$post->ID];
      }
    }  
}

// Sort posts by $post->menu_order.                                 
function menu_order_sort($a, $b) {
  if ($a->menu_order == $b->menu_order) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a->menu_order < $b->menu_order) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

These will allow us to set the `menu_order` property based on our own list, and then sort the posts in a query object based on that.

Here's how we query and sort the posts:

```
$plist = array(21, 43, 8, 44, 12);
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'post_status' => 'any',
  'post__in' => $plist 
);

// Create a new query  
$myquery = new WP_Query($args);

// set the menu_order
set_include_order($myquery, $plist);

// and actually sort the posts in our query
usort($myquery->posts, 'menu_order_sort');
```

So now we have our own query object, and the `$myquery->posts` is sorted according to our custom `menu_order_sort` function. The only tricky part now, is that we must construct our loop using our custom query object:

```
while($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
  ?>
    <div><a id="post_id_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="nb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> Post ID: <?php the_ID(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Obviously, you'd fix up the loop template code there.

I was hoping to find a solution that didn't require the use of a custom query object, perhaps by using `query_posts()` and replacing the `posts` propery on the global `$wp_query`, but I just couldn't get it to work right. With a little more time to work on it, that might have been doable.

Anyhow, see if that will get you where you need to go?

Comment: Bouy...looks a bit overkillish and doesn't work with pagination (as your sorting after querying), but +1 for a great effort to solve it without injecting something on the SQL level.

Comment: Amazing! That definitely works for posts and answers the original question. There's just one hitch, which is that I need to return attachments, not posts. I didn't realize that WP-Query() doesn't work with attachments, I've been using get_posts() ... is there any easy way to get this to work with get_posts()? I'm going to keep working on it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Updated the code to fetch attachments. :) With attachments, you have to specify `post_status` as `'any'`, because they normally use status `inherit` instead of `publish`, to reflect their parent's state.

Comment: Oh, and for future folks reading this, please note @wyrfel's comment: this will *not* work well if you need to paginate results, since the sorting doesn't happen within MySQL.

Comment: @Dougal: Many thanks, your changes did the trick. Fortunately I am not paging these results so I am 100% set.

Comment: One last note -- if you have a larger number of IDs to fetch, you might also want to add `'posts_per_page' => -1` to the `$args` array, to avoid bumping into paging limits. Actually, you might want to do this anyways, in case the site in question has its default posts_per_page set really low.

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'enforce_specific_order');
$posts = get_posts($args);
remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

function enforce_specific_order($orderby) {
    global $wpdb;
    return "FIND_IN_SET(".$wpdb->posts.".ID, '1,3,8,4,12') ASC";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this is the fastest way to return the results of a get_posts in a defined order. And besides that, it's a native solution, without hacks

```
<?php

$posts_order = array('1,3,8,4,12');
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $posts_order,
    'orderby' => 'post__in'
); 
get_posts( $args ); 

?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: It's a native solution, without hacks

Comment: Explain in your answer what is the diffenerece to the accepted answer which is using `post__in` too.

Comment: On the accepted answer, @dougal suggested to create two functions: set_include_order() and menu_order_sort(). There is no need for that. And besides, he suggested to use WP_Query instead of get_posts, as the question's author wanted.

And post__in only works if you include the 'orderby' parameter too, like i suggested

Comment: @PabloKarzin: if you look at the date on the original question, this kind of sorting was not possible in WP_Query until WordPress 3.5. Your update is correct, but it was not possible in 2011.

Comment: great answer - down vote wrong - 3.6.1 - simple and easy - Thanks!

Comment: best answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

As of WordPress 3.5, this feature is now in core. You can explicitly order posts using the "post__in" parameter. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13729

Answer (score 0):

How about just clearing the `orderby` with a filter? Right before you query your posts, put in:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', '__return_false');
```

Then, after your loop is done:

```
remove_filter('posts_orderby', '__return_false');
```

The reason for removing the filter again is in case you have other loops on the page (such as from widgets) that will need their normal explicit ordering.

Comment: Dougal: There's actually an orderby=none option, but that returns the natural order of the posts in the database, essentially orderby ID. What I'm after is a way to return my posts in the order specified in the query. It's not supported by WP_Query, so I guess I'm looking for a workaround or hack.

Comment: Well, phooey. I figured that an 'include' query would return the results in the order given if you eliminated the `orderby`. But now that I'm thinking about it, it makes sense that MySQL would return the results in natural order (it's trying to be efficient).

Comment: I was about to delete this answer of mine, but I thought it might be useful to keep around to document the database-natural-order behavior when you eliminate the orderby.