# how to retrieve WP_Query without ordering by date

Tags: wp-query, order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Orderby = none not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62546/orderby-none-not-working)

I want to use `$query = new WP_Query( 'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );` to retrieve posts by ID, I do and the result ordered by publish date but I want to retrieve in same of IDs in this example in this order: 2, 5, 12, 14, 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress 3.5, you'll be able to do this with the 'orderby' parameter set to 'post__in'.

Until then, this question is basically identical to another one, which I wrote an answer for already: [Orderby = none not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62546/orderby-none-not-working/62551#62551)

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can order by ID ascending to get those results:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ),
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);
```

see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in Codex for the full list of arguments.

Comment: this is not solution but in this case ignore 2, 5, 12, 14, 20

Comment: then edit your question to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I said that I want ordering by 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ... excuse me for my bad english